# ¿Cómo ponerle un nombre a mi programa en la terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

Ejemplo:

Para los comandos de git tu usas la palabra git "Por ejemplo **git** status"

Para los comandos de python tu usas la palabra py (o python3 en unix) "Por ejemplo **py** --version"

Ahora, cómo puedo ponerle un nombre personalizado a mi programa escrito en python para que cuando yo en mi terminal diga "**nombre**" entonces se ejecute el programa?

Comment: si es en windows podrias crear una variable de entorno

Comment: Hablando de windows, el ejecutable de `git` es `git.exe`, el ejecutable de python es `py.exe` y puedes escribir los comandos si estos ejecutables están en una ruta que se encuentre dentro del `path`. Es decir, no hay magia allí. En linux ocurre algo similar. Cuando escribes `git status` se inicia `git.exe` y se le pasa el parámetro de línea de comandos `status`.

Comment: En windows puedes escribir `where py` y te dice qué ejecutable será el invocado al escribir `py` (el primero que encuentre dentro del path). En linux puedes hacer lo mismo con el comando `which git`